# Componente AutoComplete Angular

Tags: angular

Eu estou utilizando em meu projeto os componentes da biblioteca do PrimeNg.
Alguém saberia me dizer se no componente AutoComplete (dessa biblioteca em questão) é possível setar um valor default para ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo, você consegue adicionar valor padrão utilizando a diretiva do ngModel, onde você atribuirá uma variável para receber o valor do component, essa variável pode ser iniciada com o valor default no ngInit do seu component por exemplo, de uma olhada na documentação do angular e também do PrimeNG onde já possuí um exemplo utilizando o ngModel ou o formControl.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete

Comment: Deu certo aqui agora. Eu estava fazendo isso, mas por algum motivo não estava dando certo. Por isso achei que tivesse alguma outra forma. Mas show de bola, valeu a força.